# How to create a class that implements sets

Tags: java, data-structures, set

Suppose I want to create a class `Myset` that implements `sets`, with some methods like

```
-void Insert(Object o) 
-Union(Myset a)
-Intersection(Myset a).
```

Using `Vector`/`HashSet`/`Linkedlist`.

Comment: if you implement interface then you have to implement all methods that declare in interface. can not implement some methods

Comment: And ... ? What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to create such class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just extend a data-structure class you prefer, and add/override methods as per your requirements.

Comment: i have written like `public class Myset extends HashSet { HashSet v = new HashSet(); public Myset Union (Myset a) { v.addAll(a); return v; }` But i got an error saying `Incompatible types:HashSet cannot be converted into Myset`

Comment: @tezz then why don't you initialize v as Myset v = new Myset(); OR HashSet    v = new Myset(); and  return (Myset)v if your v is HashSet reference by object of Myset

Answer (score 0):

Your class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Myset extends HashSet {
  public Myset Union(Myset a) {
    this.addAll(a); 
    return this;
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myset m = new Myset();
        m.add("Lucho");
        m.add("Rocha");
        Myset m2 = new Myset();
        m2.add("Juan");
        m2.add("Perez");
        m.Union(m2);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what are you trying to do.